# Seaborn Distplot: Data does not match probabilities

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I generated a Seaborn cumulative distplot using the following code:

```
AlphaGraphCum = sns.distplot(dfControl["alpha"],
             hist_kws={'cumulative': True},
             kde_kws={'cumulative': True}, rug=False, hist=False); 
sns.distplot(dfGoal["alpha"],
             hist_kws={'cumulative': True},
             kde_kws={'cumulative': True, 'linestyle':'--'}, rug=False, hist=False); 
sns.distplot(dfGraph["alpha"],
             hist_kws={'cumulative': True},
             kde_kws={'cumulative': True, 'linestyle':':'}, rug=False, hist=False); 
sns.distplot(dfGoalGraph["alpha"],
             hist_kws={'cumulative': True},
             kde_kws={'cumulative': True, 'linestyle':'-.'}, rug=False, hist=False)


AlphaGraphCum.set(xlabel='Alpha')
AlphaGraphCum.set(ylabel='Cumulative Probability')

#AlphaGraphCum.set_xlim(-1,1)
```

The plot has an x-axis that ranges from -2 to +2. However, when I investigate the data, the minimum is -1 and the maximum is +1. Hence, i tried limiting the axis using:

```
AlphaGraphCum.set_xlim(-1,1)
```

which I commented out in the example above. The x-axis is then correctly limited between -1 and +1. However, for x=+1, none of the lines show a y-value of 1.0, which they should since +1 is the maximum and hence the cumulative probability should equal 1.0.

Does anyone have any idea why this is not the case? Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) in Seaborn gives you an approximate density of your dataset using `kde` [(Kernel density estimation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) which assumes small "micro kernels" around the data points and add them up to create a "macro kernel" as a whole. Therefore, the kernel around the `min` and `max` certainly cross the limit because the data points on the edge (`min` and `max`) are the center of the "micro kernels". (Note: Term "micro/macro kernels" are something I just made up for explanation here.)

Suppose we have data ranging from `-10` to `10` like below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame().assign(a=np.random.randint(-10, 11, 100))
print(df.a.min(), df.a.max())

Out:
-10 10
```

If we draw the `distplot` with default settings (where `kde` is `True`),

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.distplot(df.a)
```

It shows both `histogram` which is bound between `-10` and `10` and also `kde` which is the approximation of this histogram are both shown (and of course `kde` crosses `min` and `max` limit due to the above reason).

[image]

Now, if you want to get cumulative density, then `distplot` calculates it based on `kde` like below:

```
sns.distplot(df.a, kde_kws={'cumulative': True})
```

[image]

At this point please notice that the both tails of `kde`(blue line) in 1st graph and `cumulative kde`(blue line) in 2nd graph correspond.

You may wonder if the tails exactly correspond or not since y-scales are different between 1st and 2nd graphs, so if we zoom up the y-axis of 2nd graph it looks like below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.distplot(df.a, kde_kws={'cumulative': True})
plt.ylim([0, 0.07])
```

[image]

Now 1st and 3rd graphs look similar, but only the difference is 1st one is `kde` while 3rd graph is `cumulative kde`.

Long story short, what you were plotting was the "approximated cumulative density" based on `kde`. That's why it is broader distribution (and cumulative distribution) than your actual data is (histogram).

Hope this helps.

---

EDIT: Added `cumulative kde` vs `cumulative hist`

```
sns.distplot(df.a, 
             hist_kws={'cumulative': True}, 
             kde_kws={'cumulative': True, 'linestyle':'-.'}, 
             bins=100)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! That certainly makes sense. However, is there a way in Seaborn to draw the "actual" cumulative distribution? Since my data is bound between -1 and +1, values outside of said range should not be shown since they do not make (economic) sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Marcw13 I added graphs comparing `cumulative kde` vs `cumulative hist` (with more granularity with increasing `bins` argument. This `cumulative hist` is the "actual" cumulative distribution. Hope this makes sense.